# Why does PANDAS only see one column to csv dataset with numerous columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am new to and PANDAS and I am trying to work out why the shape of this csv dataset[https://www.kaggle.com/vfoufikos/airbnb-analysis-lisbon][1] is being shown as: (237, 1)? As it appears that the dataset has 20 columns.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df = pd.read_csv('airbnb_lisbon.csv', error_bad_lines=False)

print(df.shape)
```

Could anyone please explain why?

Comment: What is the seoarator? try `sep=';'` in `read_csv()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `usecols` option to select the columns youd like to use. For example if you wanted to store dataset columns into 'df' you could use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(...., usecols=['col1', 'col2',..., 'coln'])
```

If you'd like to select all the data without specifying which columns, I'd look into specifying your delimiter, as that might be the problem you've run into. 
You can specify the type used by using `sep=','` or `sep=';'` in your `pd.read_csv()` function. Let me know if either of these work!

Comment: Great! The delimiter was a ';' so I used `sep=';'` in my `pd.read_csv()` function and now all is good (so far!) many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I had the very same problem reported by LeoGER. I've tried the three solutions that you have suggested.

1. `df = pd.read_csv(...., usecols=['col1', 'col2',..., 'coln'])` DIDN'T WORK. Jupyter reported an error
2. sep `;` DIDN'T WORK, as dataset kept the same one column stardard
3. sep `,` IT WORKED, and finally I can see the whole set of columns! :D

It seems that my mistake was that I used delimiter `;` instead of sep `,`.

Comment: Hi, this would be a more useful answer if you shared the exact text of the error, and the code snippet that worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).